# Thousands separated filter with Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have a variable in Shopify that is a string version of a number:

`product.metafields.custom_fields["total_records"] = "5324"`

I want to output that like this:

`5,324`

I tried this:

`{{ product.metafields.custom_fields["total_records"] | number }}`

But it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting with the money filters and cut off any decimals.

Comment: The problem is that some of the data does have a comma in it already, and it would convert 5,324 into $5.32 if its 5324 it converts it to $53.32